# Can't figure out this bindParam issue

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to fetch some data from a MySql db using PDO but no matter what I do, I can't get anything when using a prepared statement... please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The following code runs but returns nothing.

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banim', 'root', '');
    $uName = "banim";       //$_POST['uName'];
    $email = "Rabak@gmail.com";            //$_POST['email'];
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email OR WHERE uName = :name");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->bindParam(":name", $uName);
    $query->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $query->execute();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        print_r($query);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDOException: " . $e->getMssage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: change `print_r($query);` to `print_r($row);` and see

Comment: Your `$query` is a PDO statement class, not an array. You need to fetch the result. For instance with [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Comment: @KIKOSoftware PDO results are *iterable* for convenience.

Comment: @deceze: I see what you mean. Where is that in the manual? I can't find it. The best I can find is in the introduction of the PDOStatement class: "Represents a prepared statement and, after the statement is executed, an associated result set.", but that's not very clear.

Comment: @KIKO `PDOStatement` is documented with `implements Traversable`, and the manual has one example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#example-1027. But yeah, it's not very obvious I think.

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I missed those two hints, but it is good to know. Thank you. The Traversable interface does seem like a bit of an anomaly, but I can see why they've created it.

Answer (score 0):

What Alive To Die wrote was correct, and there was also an extra WHERE in the SQL string which also messed up the answer, this is the final code:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=banim', 'root', '');
    $uName = "banim";       //$_POST['uName'];
    $email = "Rabak@gmail.com";            //$_POST['email'];
    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from users WHERE email = :email OR uName = :name");
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $query->bindParam(":name", $uName);
    $query->bindParam(":email", $email);
    $query->execute();
    while($row = $query->fetch()){
        print_r($row);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "PDOException: " . $e->getMssage() . PHP_EOL;
}
```